# Plot Delta/Dirac function Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I know that plotting a delta function is a bit confusing in MATLAB and a potential solution can be found using the following code:

```
x = -10 : 0.1 : 10;
y = double(x == 0);
plot(x, y);
```

What if I have a signal like:
S(f) = Pa + Pb*δ(f-fo) + Pb*δ(f+fo)

How can I plot such a signal?
Thanks

Comment: How about using arrows as it's common in textbooks. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25730013/5457944) answers how to draw arrow.

Comment: @Vahid : thanks this might by a solution

Comment: See also: [Deriving dirac delta function using Matlab symbolic toolbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707851/deriving-dirac-delta-function-using-matlab-symbolic-toolbox)